# Multiple Selectors when removing a class in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wondering if there is a way to have more than one selector when removing a class in jQuery as it seems very repetitive and a waste of space. Here is what i have at the moment. the 4 lines are all removing the "error" class but from different ID's.

```
        $("#pro-desc").removeClass("error");
        $("#pro-num").removeClass("error");
        $("#price").removeClass("error");
        $("[name='delivery_status_id']").removeClass("error");
```

This code runs after a successful Ajax query and i need to reset the classes on the form.

Comment: There ***has*** to be a  dupetarget for this. Use a selector group: `$("#pro-desc, #pro-num, #price, [name='delivery_status_id']").removeClass("error");`

Comment: At least related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27240623/is-there-way-to-make-two-html-ids-link-to-one-javascript-function and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005361/jquery-attribute-selector-for-multiple-values

Comment: i could of swore that i tried that. seem to work now though. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below workaround to get class removed in a single go, This will remove error class form page.

```
$('.error').removeClass("error");
```

Comment: What if there are **other** elements with that class from which the user **doesn't** want to remove it?

Comment: nice thought, Good learning.